# How to clear Path in JavaFX GraphicsContext?

Tags: java, canvas, svg, javafx, path-2d

I am drawing a complex path to render a 3D image from scratch. It is the task and use of 3D engines is not allowed.

I am using:

```
GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
gc.appendSVGPath(svg);
gc.stroke();
```

svg is a very long string that contains svg graphic.

What I have noticed is that the value of gc.path.pointTypes.length keeps increasing by > 400k each time graphics are rendered and that slows down simulation with each loop.

How can I clear the path of GraphicsContext?

ps: It is package-private, no access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `beginPath()` before `appendSVGPath()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#beginPath--

Comment: I have really missed that one out, reading the docs. Thank You! Though beginPath() is not what you would expect.